# Are there any good-aligned sexuality-related Outsiders that aren't arshea?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, sexuality

Are there any good-aligned sexuality-related Outsiders that aren't arshea?

I'm asking because I wanted a suitable outsider for planar mentor, and no matter what I looked up, I could never find one that worked.

Comment: What does NSFW mean in this context?

Comment: Basically sexual themes

Comment: I think you should change "NSFW related" to more tangible criteria in order to make the question more answerable. "NSFW" is an internet slang for "not safe for work", it literally means any graphical content not suitable for watchin at workplace. It's unclear, how exactly a deity can be (or not to be) "NSFW related".

Comment: What part of Arshea as an [angelic patron of sexuality](https://aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Arshea) doesn't work for you? That might help narrow down what you're looking for.

Comment: The part that requires me to pick a non-unique outsider with 18HD or fewer, Arshea has too many. So maybe an outsider that would realistically serve under them?

Answer (score 6):

### Gancanagh (Passion Azata)

> Male azatas of extraordinary and radiant beauty, [gancanaghs](https://aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Gancanagh) are Elysium’s knights-errant, but they are best known as inveterate wooers of mortals and immortals alike. While gancanaghs are incorrigible flirts, a gancanagh’s true attention tends to alight on one man or woman at a time, and he throws himself into wooing and courting his current target, into a brief but earnest fling before his quicksilver passions change yet again.

Their [2nd edition lore](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=35) expands on their ties to sexuality and gives them the name of passion azatas:

> The majority of gancanaghs present themselves as male, but the concept of gender to a creature like a gancanagh, which can change its shape freely, is much more fluid and open to interpretation than for many mortals. Gancanaghs enjoy using this flexibility to confront and test mortals’ convictions when faced with fear or prejudice, but when encountering mortals who themselves are open-minded about sexuality or gender identity, they can become lifelong allies.

### Any Other Celestial

Otherwise celestial outsiders like angels, agathions, archons, or azatas could reasonably serve Arshea as an [empyreal lord of sexuality](https://aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Arshea), a unifying force for good against evil:

> Unlike many other beings of demigod-level power, [empyreal lords](https://aonprd.com/MonsterFamilies.aspx?ItemName=Empyreal%20Lord) do not divide themselves as strictly along racial lines—the term “empyreal lord” names the greatest members of the agathion, angel, archon, and azata races. While demon lords, archdevils, horsemen, and similar unique beings orchestrate the plots of their race alone— proving either unwilling or too fractious to collaborate with those not of their kind—empyreal lords seek out the commonalities of interest and purpose shared by their peers among the other celestial races.